# How to make LinearLayout Clickable with multiple textView in It?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I have a XML file like below. I want to make the first layout clickable, I used `android:clickable="true"`, but click is not working on whole part, only some part is responding to click. How to make the whole Layout clickable?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/clicableLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/task_finish"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/task_title"
            android:layout_width="195dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="@color/HeadingColor"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/DateText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textColor="@color/DateColor"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TimeText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textColor="@color/TimeColor"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask more clearly about the problem. If you want to click on the LinearLayout then set an onClickListener on the id of the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement on click listener , one way of achieving this is by the following code :

```
    yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //what after the view got clicked
        }
    });
```

Comment: Actually I have found the problem.I accidentally made a TextView inside the LinearLayout clickable.As a result portion of this TextView was not working on click.